# mvn compile in linux terminal does not have the same behaviour than Intellij compile goal in maven windows

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, build, compiler-errors

i have a behaviour difference between :

- mvn compile command in Linux terminal
- mvn compile goal in Intellij IDEA/maven windows/goal compile

I detail below :

i know why i got an error in my Linux terminal (i forgot a maven compile version in my pom.xml) but this is not the problem. The problem is to understand why the two behaviours are not similar.
So,in my linux terminal, i got an error (Compilation failure)
when i ask to my terminal my maven version i got :

```
mvn --version 
==> /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3
```

Now, i got to Intellij in the menu

```
files/settings/build tools/maven/maven home path
```

and i choose the proposed item whih is :

```
/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3
```

Then, i go to the Intellij/maven windows and i launch a compile goal.
The build is successfull !

So, question is :
why i don't have the same behaviour, as maven windows seems to use the same maven path execution ?

Perhaps the path execution of the maven windows goal isn't set from
the menu ?

```
files/settings/build tools/maven/maven home path
```

thanks by advance.

Comment: First quesiton would be: What is the compilation error? Also which version of Maven is used in IntellIJ and how does your pom file look like? And which JDK do you use on both sides? Also why using an old Maven version 3.6.3 ? Why not using most recent 3.9.5 instead?

Comment: @khmarbaise error is :"Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
" and i know how to resolve it (the <maven.compiler.target> is missing in the pom.xml). But it's not my question. My question is to understand why behaviour of [Intellij | maven windows | compile goal] is not the same as [ linux terminal | mvn compile command ], as the maven version it the same in the both configurations. So my pom.xml is dirty, it is exact, but i don't understand why Intellij seems to solve the problem, while linux command does not..

Comment: Which version of intellij do you use? That sounds you are using extreme old version of plugins etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven version is not sufficient to solve the problem.
The most important thing it the jdk version used by maven.

In Intellij IDEA, it is configured here :
settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner

There are multiple options here,
and by specify this one :

```
Use JAVA_HOME
```

i can be sure that the behaviour of my build in Intellij IDEA is the same as the build launched with the terminal command :

```
mvn clean package
```

So, all is clear now.